# Function to change random distribution in Swift?

Tags: swift, random, distribution

Does Swift have some built in methods to change the distribution of random numbers? I want to use a linear equation to define the distribution, something like y = k * x + m. When k = 0, all numbers should be equally distributed. When k = 1 the distribution should follow the line, so low x-values would be very rare while high x-values would be common. I played around in Excel and tried different strategies and finally came up with this code, which seems to work - but there must be a neater way to do this in Swift?

As a note: First I did use an array of ClosedRange instead of the tuples-approach, then used .contains. Then I changed it to an array of tuples because my code didn't work as expected. Probably another bug, but I stayed with tuples as the code works now.

```
import Foundation

/* function to create an array of tuples with upper and lower
 limits based on a linear distribution (y = k * x + m) */
func createDistributions(numbers: ClosedRange<Int>, k: Double) -> [(Double, Double)] {
    var dist = [(Double, Double)]()
    let m: Double = 0.5
    let nVal: Int = numbers.count
    var pStop: Double = 0.0

    for x in numbers {
        let t = (Double(x) + 0.5) / Double(nVal)
        let y = (k * (t - 0.5) + m) * 2.0 / Double(nVal)
        let start = pStop
        let stop = y + start
        
        dist.append((start, stop))
        pStop = stop
    }
    
    return dist
}

// create distributions based on k-value of 1.0
var result = createDistributions(numbers: 0...34, k: 1.0)


// loop ten times, creating a Double random number each time
for _ in 0...9 {
    let ran = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    
    // check in which indexed array the random number belongs to by checking lower and upper limit
    for i in 0..<result.count {
        
        // the random number belongs to the i:th element, print i
        if ran >= result[i].0 && ran <= result[i].1 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your line is supposed to be describing the [probability density function (pdf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of your distriibution, you want to use a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with the mode at one end or the other (depending on whether the slope is positive or negative). Since a pdf is required to be positive everywhere and contain an area of 1 not all slope/range combinations are feasible, so describing your goals in terms of a line specification can be problematic. Range & mode is more conventional.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would clarify your terminology. Are X's the random variables being generated? Is Y the density or the CDF or something entirely different? Where does range enter the picture?

Comment: Yes x is the random value, and y is the density I guess (I'm not really familiar with the mathematical terminology). The ranges are calculated so that each x has a range associated with it. I guess you can call it the density. If a x-value has a large range, the chance of a random number falling within this range is larger than for a x-value with a smaller range.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult here, but your comment makes no sense to me. If Y is the density, then X's are individual outcomes that occur in proportion to the density *over some range*. A density can only be linear over a bounded range of x's. Your statement "...y is the density I guess" doesn't inspire confidence that you have a firm idea of your goals, and if you want other people's help here you need to very clearly specify the details of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know math terminology, especially not in the english language. However, the ranges are there to be like a percentage of how likely the outcome is for that number. Let's move over to integers instead. Generate a random number between 1 and 10, let's call it r. If r is between 1 and 2 I would like to return 0. If r is between 3 and 10 I would like to return 1. If I loop this 100000 times I expect to get about 20% of zeros, and about 80% of ones. In this simple case it could be written as a if/else/switch-statement, but what if I scale it from two outcomes (0 or 1) to 100 outcomes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `y = kx+m` is a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF). A very good way to apply this to random number generation is an [inverse transform sampling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). I'll walk through how to develop that, step by step, so that you can adapt it to your specific needs. In the general case, this would be done with first-year calculus, but for the linear case it's easy enough to do with basic algebra and some grade-school geometry. For this example, I'll be generating a random value between 0 and 1.

(For other Americans reading along: this is the slope-intercept form we learn as `y = mx+b`. Please don't get confused that `m` here is the intercept, not the slope. I hopefully haven't mixed them up anywhere in this answer.)

To experiment with this answer, see the [GeoGebra worksheet](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/xpy6mum5) that the images come from.

The TL;DR of all of this is:

```
let u = Double.random(in: 0...1)
if k == 0 {
    return u
} else {
    return (sqrt(k*k + k*(8*u - 4) + 4) + k - 2)/(2*k)
}
```

But learning why that's the answer is the real goal.

A PDF is a function whose area between two x-values is the probability that the value is between those values. This leads to the fact that the PDF must be positive for all values in its range, and the area under it must be exactly 1 (representing a 100% chance of selecting some value over the entire range).

But a quick look at an arbitrary version of this curve shows that it may not have the right area:

[image: Graph of y=kx+m with k=0.4 and m=0.4]

For a given value of `k` there is a specific value of `m` that is valid. We can work that out by computing the area in terms of `k` and `m`, setting it to 1, and then solving for `m`. The area of the graph is a rectangle with base 1 (the range 0-1 of values we'll select) and a height `m`, plus a triangle of base 1, and height `k`. So:

```
Area = Rectangle + Triangle = 1
       m + k/2 = 1
       m = 1 - k/2
```

And substituting back into F(x):

```
F(x) = kx + 1 - k/2
```

We are also constrained that `m` cannot be less than 0, which constrains `k` to the range [0,2]. When `k` is 0, then all values are equally likely. When `k` is 2, there is a linear relationship between a value and its likelihood.

[image: Constrained PDF with linear relationship]

With a valid PDF, it is time to create a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). This is a function that represents the likelihood that a randomly selected value is no greater than the given value. These functions are constrained for the same reasons as PDFs. They must monotonically increase from zero to one over the valid range.

[image: CDF from 0 to 0.3 = 0.174]

This area can be computed just like the full area, by summing a rectangle and a triangle:

```
CDF(x) = Rectangle + Triangle
       = mx + (x/2 * (F(x) - m))
       = ... some algebra later ...
       = (k*x^2)/2 + (1-k/2)*x
```

[image: CDF function that intersects 0,0 and 1,1]

Notice that this function correctly passes through (0,0) and (1,1) as it must, and is positive over the entire range. There is no chance of a value less than zero, and there is 100% probability of a value less than or equal to one.

Almost there. An inverse transform sample applies the inverse of the CDF. That's not particularly complicated, but it is a lot of algebra, so let [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y+%3D+%28k*x%5E2%29%2F2+%2B+%281-k%2F2%29*x+for+x) do it:

```
solve y = (k*x^2)/2 + (1-k/2)*x for x
==>
x = y and k = 0
x = -(sqrt(k^2 + 8 k y - 4 k + 4) - k + 2)/(2 k) and k!=0
x = (sqrt(k^2 + k (8 y - 4) + 4) + k - 2)/(2 k) and k!=0
```

For k=0, x=y. Elsewhere, there are two solutions. Only positive values make sense here, so ignore the negative one.

[image: Inverse of CDF for k=1.5]

The red line is the function you want (this is for k=1.5). Very long road to get here, but now the code is pretty easy:

```
// `k` ranges from 0 to 2, which is confusing. Map it to range 0...1
func randomValue(distribution d: Double) -> Double {
    assert((0...1).contains(d))
    let u = Double.random(in: 0...1)

    // k ranges from 0 to 2
    let k = d * 2

    if k == 0 {
        return u
    } else {
        return (sqrt(k*k + k*(8*u - 4) + 4) + k - 2)/(2*k)
    }
}
```

And just to test it out:

```
func testRun(distribution d: Double) {
    print("Distribution for \(d)")
    let n = 10_000

    // How many results begin with a given digit after the decimal point?
    var h: [Substring:Int] = [:]
    for _ in 0..<n {
        let value = randomValue(distribution: d)
        let firstDigit = "\(value)".prefix(3).suffix(1)
        h[firstDigit, default: 0] += 1
    }

    for digit in h.keys.sorted() {
        let ratio = Double(h[digit]!)/Double(n)
        print("\(digit) -> \(ratio.formatted(.percent.precision(.fractionLength(0))))")
    }
}

testRun(distribution: 0)
testRun(distribution: 0.5)
testRun(distribution: 1)

===>
Distribution for 0.0
0 -> 10%
1 -> 10%
2 -> 10%
3 -> 11%
4 -> 10%
5 -> 10%
6 -> 10%
7 -> 10%
8 -> 10%
9 -> 10%
Distribution for 0.5
0 -> 6%
1 -> 6%
2 -> 7%
3 -> 9%
4 -> 10%
5 -> 11%
6 -> 11%
7 -> 13%
8 -> 13%
9 -> 14%
Distribution for 1.0
0 -> 1%
1 -> 3%
2 -> 5%
3 -> 7%
4 -> 9%
5 -> 11%
6 -> 13%
7 -> 15%
8 -> 17%
9 -> 19%
```

A linear equation can only push this so far. I don't believe you can get a larger difference between low-probability and high-probability values with only a linear PDF (a better mathematician may correct me here; this isn't my speciality). If you want that, I would explore applying this to larger-order polynomials. Rather than `F(x) = kx + m`, you could do the same thing with `F(x) = kx^2 + m` or even higher powers. This will take some first-year calculus, but the overall approach should be similar.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. Very good explanation - exactly what I wanted.